# Get the length of each element within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a vector:

```
df <- c(65225, 108249, 156508, 29321, 37905, 50175, 62484, 69943, 73723, 
      555, 12, 331, 1000000, 15232, 1433, 441009, 11141414, 050505)
```

and I want to find out the length of each element of the vector.

How can I do this? I tried using something from the apply-family but kept getting argument errors. Would I use a `seq_along(length(df))`?

Basically the output would be a column of the numeric and a column of the length of each observation. I would then being able to subset only those rows whose `df$dfLen > 5`.

Comment: are you wanting `nchar(df)` ? or do you just want `df[df>= 10000]`

Comment: First of all, that's a vector, not a data.frame. And also, it's filled with numbers. Numbers don't have "lengths." Do you want the number of digits in each number? Or are they really character values? R won't store leading zeros for numbers in the case of "050505"

Comment: Fyi, that is not a data.frame; it's a vector. If you want to know the order of magnitude of a number, you can use `floor(log10(x))`

Comment: <face palm> yeah sorry I meant vector. I have the option of leaving them as characters or doing an as.numeric. Basically I want to know the length if it's a character or the num of digits if it's numeric. Then I'll do a further subset of only those numbers whose length/numDigit > n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
df <- c('65225,108249,156508,29321,37905,50175,62484,69943,73723, 555, 12, 331, 1000000, 15232, 1433, 441009, 11141414, 050505')
df <- gsub(" ", "", df, fixed = TRUE) #remove spaces
dfl=strsplit(df, ",")
sapply(dfl,nchar)
```

> ```
>       [,1]
>  [1,]    5
>  [2,]    6
>  [3,]    6
>  [4,]    5
>  [5,]    5
>  [6,]    5
>  [7,]    5
>  [8,]    5
>  [9,]    5
> [10,]    3
> [11,]    2
> [12,]    3
> [13,]    7
> [14,]    5
> [15,]    4
> [16,]    6
> [17,]    8
> [18,]    6
> ```

Comment: That's the magick. Is it possible to do something like that without converting to a character vector?

Comment: Sure, the only problem is "050505", try  `sapply(df,nchar)`

Comment: The 0505050 was jut garbage data I used to make up a vector. Perfecto! Thanks @Robert.